# Will running ddrescue on a badly scratched DVD damage my DVD drive?

Tags: data-recovery, dvd

Is there any reason why running a lengthy ddrescue session on a scratched DVD would be bad for the DVD drive? Something like overheating or straining of certain components?

Answer (score 5):

Unless "lengthy" = "days and days", not really, no.  Even then I wouldn't worry about it unless it's a really old/heavily used/extremely cheap drive.

Comment: +1: The only damage you will get is wear and tear.